# a funky Makefile ...what does "cp $^ $@" do?

Tags: makefile, gfortran

the larger problem is that gdb can't find any symbols when I run it on a fortan95 code compiled using gfortran I set FFLAGS to include -g but this is a VERY FUNKY makefile (I think it creates auxilary files for using in determining how to process the code that needs to be compiled) so I'm not sure that the -g is getting stuck everywhere it needs to.  But I was wondering if anyone could tell me what 
cp $^ $@ 
does? google won't tell me.

Answer (score 0):

In a make rule, the `$@` variable expands to the name of the target and the `$^` variable expands to the names of the prerequisites.  So assuming that the target in this situation is a directory, this will copy all the prerequisite files into that directory.

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables